# row() or col() members of arma::Cube seem not to work

Tags: c++, armadillo

In using armadillo's Cube arrays (3D), I'm having some difficulty using col() or row() functions. They work just fine on an arbitrary 2D matrix (e.g., A.col(0)), and the related cols() and rows() functions do work as expected on cube arrays (such as Q.cols(0,1); see below), but row() and col() do not seem to work for this data type. Here's a minimum working example, with output included within as comments:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <armadillo>
    int main() {
        arma::Cube<double> Q(2,2,2,arma::fill::randu);
        Q.print();

    // [cube slice 0]
    //   0.7868   0.7107
    //   0.2505   0.9467
    // [cube slice 1]
    //   0.0193   0.2513
    //   0.4049   0.0227

    // The rows() and cols() function work fine to give me row- and columnwise access:

        Q.rows(0,0).print();

    // [cube slice 0]
    //   0.7868   0.7107
    // [cube slice 1]
    //   0.0193   0.2513

        Q.cols(0,0).print();

    // [cube slice 0]
    //   0.7868
    //   0.2505
    // [cube slice 1]
    //   0.0193
    //   0.4049

    // So far so good. I assumed row() and col() functions would
    // simply access single rows or columns, respectively, through 
    // the slices. But this is not the case. If I try to access 
    // the row() or col() functions via .print(), a core dump ensues.
    // If I examine the size of these objects, they are either
    // empty or extremely large.

        std::cout << size(Q.row(0)) << std::endl;
    // 0x0x0
        std::cout << size(Q.col(0)) << std::endl;
    // 0x0x18446744073709551615
        return 0;
    }
```

This indicates I'm misusing these functions (at least on *Cube* objects), although the documentation shows Q.row(row_number) and Q.col(col_number) to be used in this way. However, as mentioned above, .row() or .col() access using a *2D matrix* works as expected.

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Your code and also 'Q.col(0).print()` worked fine for me (using armadillo-9.200.5 at Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Might be a bug in Armadillo?  Perhaps file a bug report with the developers.

Comment: Claes and hbrerkere, apologies for the late reply, and thanks for the response. This may be a consequence of using 9.200.4 (the latest available build on Fedora 29), as this behavior is *not* shown in 9.200.5 (tested on a Gentoo machine), consistent with Claes' results; I am currently testing an arma build using Conrad's git repo on the Fedora machine, will report back ...

Comment: @ClaesRolen hbrerkere Thanks again: this issue seems to be confined to 9.200.4, as building the current git version (9.200.6) shows this problem to be corrected -- i.e., .col() and .row() then work as expected. So I guess this problem now resides downstream with Fedora ...